# Sorting in reverse numeric order on subfield in a multi-field sort

Tags: shell, command-line, sort

I'm trying to use GNU sort on a directory/file listing, eg (subset of much longer listing):

```
exams2008/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum08.pdf
exams2009/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019.pdf
exams2010/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2010.pdf
exams2011/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2011.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2012.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2013.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2013.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2014.pdf
```

I am already sorting this successfully on the filename (4th field) followed by the season (3rd field), eg

```
$ sort -t/ -k4 -k3,3 
exams2012/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2013.pdf
exams2009/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019.pdf
exams2008/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum08.pdf
exams2010/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2010.pdf
exams2011/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2011.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2013.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2014.pdf
```

But for each block like this, I need them in descending year order as the third sort criterion, using the four digits from position 6 thru 9 of the first field. If I use:

```
sort -t/ -k4 -k3,3 -k1.6nr,1.9
```

which looks as if it ought to work, but it does not sort that third criterion in reverse numeric order:

```
exams2012/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2013.pdf
exams2009/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019.pdf
exams2008/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum08.pdf
exams2010/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2010.pdf
exams2011/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2011.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2013.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2014.pdf
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but related questions don't address this specific condition (third sort criterion, subfield, numeric, reverse) and I can't identify a reason why it fails.

Comment: That's all equivalent to `sort -t/ -k4`. That sort key is different for all lines, so no other key are considered.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want: `sort -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1r`

Answer (score 4):

To make sure I added a new line in the example data:

```
exams2008/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum08.pdf
exams2009/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019.pdf
exams2010/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2010.pdf
exams2011/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2011.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2012.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2012.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2013.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2013.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2014.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4029Sum2014.pdf <- This is added by me
```

I added that to illustrate that the sorting also depends on the 4th field. It has the same year and the same 3rd field, but different 4th field. If I understood correctly, that should do what you want.

```
sort -t/ -k3,3 -k1.6nr,1.9 -k4 file
```

Output:

```
exams2013/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2013.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Autumn/ZY4019Aut2012.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2014.pdf
exams2014/Zoology/Summer/ZY4029Sum2014.pdf
exams2013/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2013.pdf
exams2012/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2012.pdf
exams2011/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2011.pdf
exams2010/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum2010.pdf
exams2009/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019.pdf
exams2008/Zoology/Summer/ZY4019Sum08.pdf
```

First sort the 3rd field (`-k3,3`), then the first field chars 6-9 should be reverse and numeric (`-k1.6nr,1.9`), and at last the 4th field (`-k4`).

Comment: Very close, thank you. In fact as I said, that was a fragment of a much larger listing -- the overall dataset must primarily be in the order of the first 6 chars of the last field. But I'll work on it: it still doesn't explain why specifying the subfield-key as the last sort parameter makes it fail, though. A bug?

Comment: Hah. Bug. If I change the first sort key to make it use a subfield of the last field (4.1,4.6) then the program honors the third sort key correctly.